# How to call an imported module knowing its name as a string?

Tags: python, python-import

I am writing an application that should test the solution of many students.
I have structure like this

```
app/
    students/
        A/
            lab1/
                solution.py
            lab2
                solution.py
        B/
            lab1/
                solution.py
        C/
    test.py
```

I want to import the solution file in the testing module and run the main method.
I know there is `__import__` function that returns a module object, but I don't know how to call main method.

My code:

```
import os


def get_student_names():
    return os.listdir('students')

def test(name, lab):
    if lab not in os.listdir('/'.join(['students',name])):
        return f"{lab} not found"
    if 'solution.py' not in os.listdir('/'.join(['students',name,lab])):
        return "solution file not found"
    module = __import__('.'.join(['students',name,lab,'solution']))
    # module.name.lab.solution.main()

def main():
    student_names = get_student_names()
    for student in student_names:
        result = test(student, "lab1")
```

I want to call `module.name.lab.solution.main()` but the `module` is `students`. How to switch to `solution` submodule?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want to call module.name.lab.solution.main() but the module is students" I don't understand the problem you are describing. When you uncomment the `module.name.lab.solution.main()` line and try the code (with some test modules), **what happens**? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? Did you try to test this setup (i.e., supplying your own `solution.py` file to see what happens)? What result do you get for `module`? What attributes does it have?

Comment: (Aside from that, **please** consider the possibility that one of your students could submit malicious code, for example a program to try to erase your hard drive.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your most immediate problem is that you aren't returning anything from `test` so, `result` will always be `None`. The second and most important problem you have is that you don't really have any modules. You actually have a bunch of random folders with arbitrary python scripts in them. This means `__import__` is going to be quite unfriendly to you.

if we run this line

```
__import__('students.A.lab1.solution').main()
```

we get back this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'students' has no attribute 'main'
```

`students`? We're supposed to be in `solution`! That's a problem. There is a way to do this without worrying about converting and maintaining your individual folders as actual modules.

---

First, students must call `main` in their solution.

ex:

```
def main():
    print('hello, world')
    
main()
```

Secondly, run their script. If the command fails it is going to tell you the script doesn't exist and move on to the next student.

```
import os

#change this to however you call python
PY   = 'python3'

#lab format strings
LAB1 = '{} "students/{}/lab1/solution.py"'
LAB2 = '{} "students/{}/lab2/solution.py"'


def main(lab:str) -> None:
    for student in os.listdir('students'):
        os.system(lab.format(PY, student))
            
    
main(LAB1)
```

As highlighted by @KarlKnetchel, the above code has all of the same vulnerabilities as your original concept. This is NOT safe. You should definitely consider running this in a sandbox, if you use it.